# how to program esp32 after assembly on a PCB

Tags: embedded, esp32

advice please for a starter. if I ordered the assembly service for a PCB with an esp32 board. how can program it afterwards if its already soldered?

cheers

Comment: What does "PCB with an esp32 board" mean? Isn't esp32 some manner of board in itself? Why would programming it be a problem? Also, these kind of questions are better asked at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/. A picture would be helpful for understanding the question.

Comment: Should you not have considered that _before_ designing the board?  ESP32 modules are programmed serially via an on-board USB serial bridge.

Comment: @Clifford, you mean dev boards? modules don't have USB

Comment: @Juraj probably - misspoke - that is ambiguous.  What is important is what does the OP mean?  Because he clearly says "board". It is not clear if he has a DIL board as a mezzanine on _his_ board or just a module placed on his board. If he is using a module and did not break out either the UART or the JTAG pins on his board, then truly he has gone to production too early with an unusable design.  It remains off-topic in any event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jumper the device to start into the serial bootloader, connect the UART to an off-board USB-UART adapter, and run the well known python tool for downloading just as you would with the dev board.

Or get the chip to tristate the flash pins, contact them with something else and directly write the flash.

Or program the flash chip before soldering it in place.

Next time around have connector, edge fingers, or pads for a pogo-pin spring contact jig.